# Automatic Telegram Media Button with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, telegram

I've been trying to press the "photo or video" button with Python-selenium:

[image: the button and source code]

I also tried to use javascript in python but it didn't work either.

My Code:

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="column-center"]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[7]/div[1]/div[1]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="column-center"]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[7]/div[2]'))).click();time.sleep(3)
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 8).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="message-compose"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]'))).click()
```

And then with an answer I received in a previous post I shared, I changed my code to:

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="column-center"]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[7]/div[1]/div[1]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="column-center"]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[7]/div[2]'))).click();time.sleep(3)
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 8).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'Photo or Video')]"))).click()
```

And now, I'm receiving this error:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <span class="i18n btn-menu-item-text">...</span> is not clickable at point (996, 657). Other element would receive the click: <div class="c-ripple"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, I answered you on your previous question, but you deleted it.  And even changed your name.

Comment: Share relevant html in text format here.

Comment: Firstly, sorry for that Prophet. Stackoverflow closed sending comments and i wasn't able to share a new post so I created this account. Secondly, I updated the post. You can see the source code and the button from the link above cruisepandey.

Comment: You can always add comments under closed posts. And if it helped you could accept my answer...

Comment: @JohnNiyazi : on that HTML, right click and select copy outer HTML, and then share that here in text format. It's hard to read from an image